# Sql comparing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I want to select everything from the product table where the name is not equal to a name existing in ordered_products. I tried this but it didnt work:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE naam IS NOT (SELECT naam FROM ordered_products)
```

Comment: missing IN after NOT  and remove is :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `NOT IN` predicate like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE naam NOT IN (SELECT naam 
                   FROM ordered_products
                   WHERE naam IS NOT NULL);
```

But this is not safe, in case there is any `NULL` values of the `naam` coming from the other table, thats why I added `WHERE naam IS NOT NULL` to the subquery. Better off, use `JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM product
LEFT JOIN ordered_products o ON p.naam = o.naam
WHERE p.naam IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE naam NOT IN (SELECT naam FROM ordered_products)
```

OR

```
SELECT P.* 
FROM product P
LEFT JOIN  ordered_products O ON P.naam = O.naam
```

Hope this helps